# Check if core data attributes, contains value before adding new one

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I'd like to check whether the category name I'm about to create already exists or not, in the core data store.

If, it exists, then I should display an alert view and not create it. If it doesn't exist, then I can carry on with the creation of my new category.

```
 func createCategory() {
            let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Category", inManagedObjectContext: context!)
            let categoryEntity = Category(entity: entity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: context)
            let index = pickerView.selectedRowInComponent(0)
            let color = categoryColor[index]
            let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Category")
                fetchRequest.fetchLimit = 1
            let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name = %@", name.text)
            let fetchResults = context!.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: &error) as? [Category]

            if let results = fetchResults {
                var requiredCategory : Category
                if (results.count > 0) {
                    requiredCategory = results[0] as Category
                } else {
                    requiredCategory = Category(entity: categoryEntity, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: context!)
                    requiredCategory.name = name.text
                    // set the other properties for the Category as necessary
                }
                category?.name = requiredCategory
                category!.descript = descriptionField.text
                category!.color = color
                println(category!.name)
                context?.save(nil)
            name.text = ""
            descriptionField.text = ""
            }
        }
```

Comment: You aren't actually asking a question. What problem do you have?

Comment: The above function create a new category and save it in my core data. My entity Category has a name, description, and a colour. My problem is, i'd like to know check if the new category that is about to be created exists in the core data, when I click on the save button. If it does, then it won't be created and show an alert message, if it doesn't exist then i can create a new category. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should create the `fetchRequest` and execute it before you create `categoryEntity`. Then, check `results.count`. If the count is `> 0` you already have one and you should display your alert. If it isn't then you can create `categoryEntity`, configure it and save it.

Note that you may want to use `=[cd]` in your predicate to avoid multiple categories with the same name but different capitalisation.